# Enterprise Keyword Column not being crawled SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search, metadata, enterprise-keywords

In my organization, user are starting to utilize Enterprise Metadata and Keywords feature available in SharePoint document library. But for some reason items within that column are not being displayed in search results.

I checked the URL in central admin search service application page. It says it was successfully crawled. I am still not able to search using those keywords.

Can someone shed some light on this behavior.

Comment: My best bet is that they're got indexed as crawled properties. You need to map them to managed properties and set them to searchable. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667.aspx

Comment: I cant see the keyword I inserted in the list listed in CA crawled properties. This keyword was created in the library itself not managed in CA level.

Comment: Have you tried using Hastags instead? (Use #SharePoint) these are indexed and returned  inSearch if you query #SharePoint